# Get a button working in a table From JSON Href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, json

```
    <table class="pull-left table table-fill">
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <th class="table-hover">Name</th>
    <th class="table-hover">Price</th>

</tr>
</thead>
</table>


</body>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script>

      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          crossDomain: true,
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          url: 'api link here',
          success: function (json) {
               //var json = $.parseJSON(data);
               for(var i =0;i < json.results.collection1.length;i++) {
                 var title = json.results.collection1[i].EventsUK.text;
                 var href = json.results.collection1[i].EventsUK.href;
             $("table").append("<tbody><tr><td>"+title+"</td><td>"+href+"</td></tr></tbody>");
           }
     },
     error: function(error){
          console.log(error);
     }
   });
</script>
```

I receive the href from the website. How would i get the href into a button link? To display in the same place (the table. I have tried adding all the button commands i could to the code which hasnt worked, I have also tried adding it infront he of href and infront of the plus symbols.

Sam

Comment: You want a button to work like a link?

Comment: I get a link back from the json, I'm wanting that link to become a clickable button that followsthrough to that link

Comment: and you have already extracted the correct values in `var title` and `var href`? you just want a workin link with that href?

Comment: Basically the var href gives me a link back in a table, instead of the link im wanting a button to go through the link:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links are **not** resolved by themselves in HTML. You need to use the `<a>` tag instead. It's very dirty, but the quickest trick to do that, given your code, is changing your `append` into

```
$("table").append(""
    + "<tbody>"
    + "<tr>"
    + "<td>" + title + "</td>"
    + "<td><a href=" + href + ">" + href + "</a></td>"
    + "</td>"
    + "</tr>"
    + "</tbody>"
);
```

... though I don't get the meaning of the table.

Comment: @SamRoberts, yes, I did miss the closing `</tr>`. Just corrected. Does that work now?

Comment: The information is still there, but is not turning into a clickable link still :(